# PAge redirecting to first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am currently creating a webpage using Jquery UI tabs. There are 3 tabs , where in the first tab just displays a message saying "hello" and "have a great day". the 2nd and the 3rd tab have another page which performs some operation. The pages have a place to upload a file, and once a button is clicked, it perform some operations on the file and the result is displayed in a text box.  Now the problem is as soon as i click a button in any of these 2 pages, my main page gets redirected to the first tab which displays "hello". How do I change my code so that my 2nd or 3rd tab is intact even after I submit a button?

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


$(function()
{
             $("#menu  ul li a").each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                });

             $("#menu ul li a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#menu ul li a").each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                });

                $(this).addClass("active");
});      
$("#menu").tabs({ fx: {opacity:"toggle"}} );
});
```

and my HTML code:

```
<body  background="wood_bg.jpg" >

<div id="menu">
   <ul>
     <li> <a href="#tab-1" >Welcome</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-2" title="Decode">Decode Support key</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-3" title="Response">Response Generator</a></li>
   </ul>

<div id="tab-1" >
    <div id ="main">
             <p> HELLO </p>
             <p> HAVE A GREAT DAY </p>

            </div>
            </div>

 <div id="tab-2">
    <div id ="main">

   <p>   MY 2nd TAB PAGE HERE </p>

            </div>
            </div>


 <div id="tab-3">
    <div id ="main">

   <p>   MY 3nd TAB PAGE HERE </p>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please edit your submission?

Comment: he forgot to ask the question!!!may bee

Comment: Please reedit your code for clarity, everything after $(function(){ is commented out so we dont know what is actually running etc.

Comment: sorry guys for the lack in clarity!! I have edited it now.. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can redirrect from your conroller to the page with parameter e.g. `?tab=3`

On your page make JS to analyse 'page' parameter and show the proper tab, something like that:

```
$(function() {
  // get params from window.location.href
  var tab = params.tab || 1;
  $("#tab-"+tab).click();
});
```

How to get params from location - for example here: http://blogosys.com/2011/09/how-to-read-url-parameters-from-address-bar-using-javascript.html